# How to resolve my errors in Mongodb on Linux?

Tags: mongodb

I installed on my linux mogodb and it worked but after about 8 months later I can't remember what happened, and I uninstalled and reinstalled it and it worked. Now it doesn't work when I uninstall it and reinstall it. My command line to uninstall it and like

```
sudo service mongod stop
sudo apt-get purge mongodb-org *
sudo rm -r / var / log / mongodb
sudo rm -r / var / lib / mongodb.
```

I followed the following url to install it; https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mongodb/mongodb_quick_guide.htm

My error is when I put "sudo apt-get update", it looks like this

```
E: Unable to recover http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu- 
upstart/dists/dist/InRelease The plain signed file is not valid, what was received is 
"NOSPLIT". Perhaps the network requires authentication.
E: The http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart dist InRelease deposit is not 
signed.
N: Updates from such a repository cannot be done securely, and are therefore disabled by 
default.
N: See the apt-secure (8) manual pages for creating repositories and user configuration 
details.
```

Comment: Looking around at general `NOSPLIT` errors, it looks like it's possible that there's a network-related issue. You should check to make sure that your outgoing requests aren't being blocked by a firewall, that a proxy isn't being used by your ISP, etc. Overall this doesn't appear to be a MongoDB-specific error, so you'll need to change the direction of your search.

Comment: I would suggest taking this question to [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) instead. This isn't really a StackOverflow type of question, and SuperUser should be able to better assist you with problems related to `apt`/`apt-get`.